# Request to merge [election] and [presidential-election] tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Any question about [presidential-election](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/presidential-election) would also be about [election](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/election).[The page on tag synonyms](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) says. Also, this article on Wikipedia: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presidential_election explains that presidential elections are the same thing as elections but for presidents.

> or multiple tags that mean the same thing -- it's a good idea to propose a tag synonym

If you think these tags shouldn’t be marked as synonyms please explain why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally I'd agree with you that we shouldn't have a tag that's a perfect subset of another tag. We certainly could replace it with a combination of [president](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/president) and [election](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/election). However, I think we should make an exception here because of how common questions about (usually US) Presidential Elections are.

There are currently 566 questions in [presidential-election](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/presidential-election), and it's the 8th most common tag. That alone should make us hesitant to remove it. Beyond that, it shows that [presidential-election](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/presidential-election) is a distinct topic that people are actually using to identify their questions. That makes sense: presidential elections are a big deal, especially in the US which is home to a disproportionate amount of our users, and people come here with questions about these elections, not about elections or presidents in general.

[presidential-election](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/presidential-election) provides a clear way to organize and find the many, *many* questions about US (or French, etc.) presidential elections and I think the tag should remain

Comment: Wouldn’t it make sense to include the electoral college or something else possibly in the tag wiki then, to specify? Right now it doesn’t seem very specific.

Comment: You’re right that we should make the usage guidance more clear. It’s not US specific, though, so the electors college wouldn’t belong in the tag wiki.

Comment: @divisiban okay, how would you suggest to make the tag wiki more specific

Answer (score 2):

These should not be merged together as you can get more specific with the presidential-election tag and it is nice to have that difference. There are differences between the two that are nice to keep seperate.

Comment: Why is it nice to have that difference? And why is getting slightly more specific with the tag important, because the country the election is for is going to be mentioned anyways, so specifying in the tag isn’t going to matter. Also, what differences are there between the two?

Comment: Because there are areas that only apply to a presidential election and having that as a tag helps determine what is being asked.

Comment: What areas apply to a presedential election and not a normal election

Comment: The entire electoral college as a quick example. Just because two tags are related doesn't mean you have to combine them

Comment: that is not for all presedential elections, only some. Then they should be labeled as “electoral college” and/or “elections”

Comment: nothing about electoral colleges is mentioned in the tag wiki about presedential elections

Comment: @Yay The tag wiki doesn't cover everything and it shouldn't have to and since presidential-clearly has a distinct meaning I see no gain from merging it with election.

Comment: the only difference between an election and of a presedential election is that a presedential election is the election of a president. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presidential_election.

Comment: @Yay That is not the only difference as many presidential elections have special rules that only apply to them. Also there is no reason to go back and forth with me on this as you should be providing your reasoning for combining the tags in your own answer not debating the merits of an answer that doesn't agree with you.